# Sorting a integer list without a sort command

Tags: java

So I have this code:

```
public class SortedIntList extends IntList
{   
    private int[] newlist;

    public SortedIntList(int size) 
    {
        super(size);
        newlist = new int[size];
    }

    public void add(int value)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            int count = 0,
                current = list[i];

            if(current < value)
            {
                newlist[count] = current;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                newlist[count] = value;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yet, when I run the test, nothing prints out. I have the system.out.print in another class in the same source.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: Print code from comment:

```
 public class ListTest 
 { 
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      { 
           SortedIntList myList = new SortedIntList(10); 
           myList.add(100); 
           myList.add(50); 
           myList.add(200); 
           myList.add(25); 
           System.out.println(myList); 
      }
 }
```

EDIT2: Superclass from comment below

```
 public class IntList 
 { 
      protected int[] list; 
      protected int numElements = 0; 

      public IntList(int size) 
      { 
           list = new int[size]; 
      }

      public void add(int value) 
      {
           if (numElements == list.length) 
                System.out.println("Can't add, list is full"); 
           else { 
                list[numElements] = value; numElements++;
           }
      }

      public String toString() 
      { 
           String returnString = "";
           for (int i=0; i<numElements; i++) 
                returnString += i + ": " + list[i] + "\n"; 
           return returnString;
      }
 }
```

Comment: So, you've got a problem with printing, but you won't show us the code where you've got the print command?

Comment: "I have the system.out.print in another class in the same source" - Not helpful. Show us.

Comment: The code that adds a value looks highly suspicious.

Comment: public class ListTest
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  SortedIntList myList = new SortedIntList(10);
  myList.add(100);
  myList.add(50);
  myList.add(200);
  myList.add(25);
  System.out.println(myList);
 }
}
Not sure why it is coming out like this.. i dont use this site much,

Comment: your print statement is trying to print the memory addess of the list.

Comment: So,  how do I fix it?
Maybe list = newlist;?

Comment: Do you have a `toString()` in `SortedIntList` or `IntList`?

Comment: You should implement a toString method that returns a string formatted the way you want it to print.  I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to return.  e.g. if you wanted to return a string of every item in the list, you should build a string containing every item in the list and return it from your toString method

Comment: I do, but im still struggling to get it to work

Comment: Ignoring that you aren't printing the correct way, you should be getting *something* printed. How are you running the code?

Comment: What do you mean by how, I am compiling the code then running it.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

This is superseded by my later answer.  I have left it here, rather than deleting it, in case the information in it is useful to you.

---

Two problems.

(1) You define `list` in the superclass, and presumably that's what you print out; but you add elements to `newList`, which is a different field.

(2) You only add as many elements to your new list as there are in your old list.  So you'll always have one element too few.  In particular, when you first try to add an element, your list has zero elements both before and after the add.

You should probably have just a single list, not two of them.  Also, you should break that `for` loop into two separate loops - one loop to add the elements *before* the value that you're inserting, and a second loop to add the elements *after* it.

Comment: list is initialized at 10, so its length is 10

Comment: But when the list is constructed, it is given a size in the constructor.

Comment: The list declared in THIS class is given a size of 10.  But we are iterating through the list declared in the superclass.  We can't see how that has been constructed.

Comment: protected int[] list;
 protected int numElements = 0;
 
 public IntList(int size)
 {
  list = new int[size];
 }

Comment: @DavidWallace the superclass code is posted.  Looks like it is still a 10 size array

Comment: Oh, I see the superclass. Doesn't this just give an array full of zeroes? And it will always be an array of zeroes, because if you try to insert a positive number into it, it will get to the end of the array before it finds a suitable spot for it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through the logic of how you want it to work here:

first you make a new sorted list passing 10 to the constructor, which make an integer array of size 10.

now you call your add method passing 100 into it.  the method sets position 0 to 100

now you add 50, the method sets 50 in position 0 and 100 in position 1

now you add 200, which gets placed at position 2

and you add 25. which gets set to position 0, and everything else gets shuffled on down

then your method will print out everything in this list.

So here are your problems:

For the first add, you compare current, which is initialized at 0, to 50.  0 will always be less than 50, so 50 never gets set into the array.  This is true for all elements.

EDIT:  Seeing the super class this is how you should look to fix your code:

```
public class SortedIntList extends IntList
{   
    private int[] newlist;
    private int listSize;

    public SortedIntList(int size) 
    {
        super(size);
        // I removed the newList bit becuase the superclass has a list we are using
        listSize = 0; // this keeps track of the number of elements in the list
    }

    public void add(int value)
    {
        int placeholder;
        if (listSize == 0)
        {
            list[0] = value; // sets first element eqal to the value
            listSize++; // incriments the size, since we added a value
            return;   // breaks out of the method
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        {
            if (list[i] > value) // checks if the current place is greater than value
            {
                placeholder = list[i]; // these three lines swap the value with the value in the array, and then sets up a comparison to continue
                list[i] = value;
                value = placeholder;
            }
        }
    list[i] = value; // we are done checking the existing array, so the remaining value gets added to the end
    listSize++;  // we added an element so this needs to increase;
    }

    public String toString() 
    { 
        String returnString = "";
        for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++) 
            returnString += i + ": " + list[i] + "\n"; 
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but where is it being compared to 0, in the if statement?

Comment: unless I'm wrong, int get initialized to 0 for arrays in java.  Otherwise its Null, or junk data (any number possibly) in which case its worse trouble.

Comment: public class IntList
{
 protected int[] list;
 protected int numElements = 0;

 public IntList(int size)
 {
  list = new int[size];
 }
 
 public void add(int value)
 {
  if (numElements == list.length)
   System.out.println("Can't add, list is full");
  else
  {
   list[numElements] = value;
   numElements++; 
  }
 }
 
 public String toString()
 {
  String returnString = "";
  for (int i=0; i<numElements; i++)
   returnString += i + ": " + list[i] + "\n";
   return returnString;
 }
}

Comment: @MarshallTigerus It's basically impossible to get junk data in Java without using unsafe libraries/JNI. Class-level variables are automatically initialized if not explicitly initialized at declaration or in a constructor; and function-local variables must be assigned a value on any given code path before being used on that path, or it's a compile error.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I've been working a lot in C lately, so I'm always wary of unititialized variables.  I figured Java was "safe"

Answer (score 0):

Now that I see the superclass, the reason why it never prints anything is clear.  `numElements` is always zero.  You never increment it because you never call the superclass version of the `add` method.

This means that the loop in the `toString` method is not iterated at all, and `toString` always just returns empty string.